# How to prevent from session restore on back button in ubuntu?

Tags: php

Guys please tell me how to prevent from session restore on back button in ubuntu ?

```
session_cache_limiter( FALSE ); 

session_start();

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE);
```

this works in xp but not in ubuntu.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are you talking about XP and Ubuntu as being hosts of the site __or__ as browsing clients of the site? This is important as sessions are stored both on the server and referenced by a cookie on the users machine.

Comment: I am talking about Mozilla firefox in ubuntu. I have done all session clear thing but still it is not working